# Facebook tutorial iphone

Tags: cocoa-touch

How to use the Facebook iphone sdk?I want to make a facebook application that will have a search bar and after entering data in the search bar whatever information will be returned from the facebook database i need to display it in the tableview...please help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

From reading through [Facebook's iPhone SDK](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_iPhone_SDK), it looks like you can [construct a Facebook Query Language (FQL) query](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_iPhone_SDK#Calling_the_Platform_API) and asynchronously receive the results which you'd use to populate your UITableView.

See the iPhone SDK Samples for how to do UITableView population and a search box.